# How to turn a DSL wireless modem to a wifi hub

Tags: wireless-networking

I used to use DSL for my home internet and used [Qwest Q1000 wireless modem](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005GGD51O). Now I switched to cable and use wireless router to cover the home. One problem is I just bought a desktop and I like to put it in a place far away from the router. The desktop only has cable interface, it does not receive wifi.

The obvious solution is I go buy that little USB dongle which can receive wifi and plug it to the desktop. But before doig that, I am wondering if somehow I can re-use the Q1000 modem.

The modem has 4 LAN ports and it has wifi antenna. I tried connecting the desktop to Q1000's LAN port, the system shows wire connection is in place, but I cannot access internet.

It seems to me Q1000's wifi function is to broadcast the wifi signal out instead of receiving signal.

I went to the Q1000 configuration page by going to web page of "192.168.0.1", it is not clear how to set it up. I also wonder one thing, my home wifi is encrypted, so if I want to let Q1000 to join the wifi, I need to somehow type in the password, I am not sure how to do that either.

Anyway, maybe this thing cannot be used in this fashion. If you have any suggestion, please shed some light.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use a wireless router as a wireless network adapter?](http://superuser.com/questions/366602/use-a-wireless-router-as-a-wireless-network-adapter), http://superuser.com/questions/459327/use-wireless-router-to-receive-wifi-and-send-via-ethernet

Answer (score 0):

The dsl modem probably won't do wireless extending of an existing wireless network (eg: extending the wifi network without wires).

Disable dhcp, and plug the lan port into your existing cable (dhcp) modem. You're all set. If it doesn't work, then there's nothing else that you can do. (eg: the dsl modem will not work as a wireless bridge).

ive done this with a bellsouth netopia dsl modem and a windstream dsl modem.

You might just want to get a dedicated wifi extender. They can be quite tricky to get working. If you go this route, get the same brand as your wireless router (eg if you get another netgear wifi router, get a netgear extender)

Comment: I tried that: disable DHCP of the DSL wireless model and connect it to the cable wireless router; then take it back to connect to my desktop, it does not work, my desktop still cannot connect to internet. I guess this is it, the route does not work.  One weird thing - at my desktop, I cannot access the DSL modem configuration page any more at this point, "192.168.0.1" is not accessible.